# What's default TTL in Redis?

Tags: redis, ttl

I can't find anywhere online what is default TTL in Redis.
I know that I can set TTL for specific SET, but don't know what is default TTL. 
Can someone tell me what default time to live is in Redis?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The keys with no expiration time set will not expire.

If you mean [TTL command](https://redis.io/commands/ttl) specifically, starting with v2.8, it will return -2 if no `EXPIRE` value is set.

Edit:
Itamar Haber's comment is true, I recalled false: There is no such setting in [redis config](https://redis.io/topics/config) for a global TTL. So I deleted the part about that.

Edit2: Also see the link to the official docs about default expiration of keys here: https://redis.io/commands/expire#appendix-redis-expires

Comment: There is no such config

Comment: is there somewhere in the docs that state this ?  I'm happy to have found the answer here, but I was hoping to find it in the docs.

Answer (score 64):

There is no default TTL. By default, keys are set to live forever.

Comment: That's all  i wanted to know. Thank you a lot.

Comment: what if I set this value to 0 ?

Comment: @SimonSu It deletes the key.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose value set to '-1' by default which means **forever.**

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set datakey "my-data"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> TTL datakey
(integer) -1
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

### REDIS Docs says

---

Starting with Redis 2.8 the return value in case of error changed:

The command returns -2 if the key does not exist.
***The command returns -1 if the key exists but has no associated expire.***